# Converting an integer to a string of escaped hex (NOT bytes)

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to come up with a way to convert an integer to a ***string*** of escaped hex, as if it was coded that way... for example:

x = '\xab\xcd\xff\xff'

I have tried the following function, but it appears that chr() only does this for characters with the integer value 160 and below:

```
def int2chr(val, size):  
    out = ''
    for _ in range(size):  
        tmp = val & 0xff  
        val >>= 8  
        out = f'{chr(tmp)}{out}'  
    return out`
```

From this, I get:

```
>>> int2chr(0xabcdffff, 4)  
'����'  
>>>
```

I would like it to return '\xab\xcd\xff\xff' instead...

This doesn't work any better:

```
def int2chr(val, size): 
    out = ''
    for _ in range(size): 
        tmp = val & 0xff 
        val >>= 8  
        out = f'\\x{hex(tmp)[2:]}{out}'  
    return out
```

```
>>> int2chr(0xabcdffff,4)  
'\\xab\\xcd\\xff\\xff'  
>>>
```

The closest I've been able to come gives me bytes, not a string:

b'\xab\xcd\xff\xff'

I am very surprised that there isn't an easy way to do this. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Is your desired output equivalent to the string *literal* `'\xab\xcd\xff\xff'` or to the *printed* string `'\xab\xcd\xff\xff'`? In the case of the former, your first code is correct; Python just has different options to display the character, similar to how `'\x41' == 'A'`. For the first code, `int2chr(0xabcdffff, 4) == '\xab\xcd\xff\xff'` holds true. For the second code, ``int2chr(0xabcdffff, 4) == r'\xab\xcd\xff\xff'`` holds true.

Comment: I am working with an infra that seems to take that unreadable string literal and converts it to a string reading 'c2abc38dc3bfc3bf' ... with the \xnn representation, this does not happen. The code appears to work fine for all character values from 0 to 160 ... above that, I get this weird unicode-ish output

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide more details about the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The first attempt should have worked fine, the problem may be with your console output.

Comment: @steve That is because the terminal with which you view the output cannot represent those glyphs. For me the output of the first code *and the literal `'\xab\xcd\xff\xff'`* renders as `'«Íÿÿ'` when printed.

Comment: Basically, you have to figure out if whatever reads your data expect a string of the four characters `\xab` `\xcd` ... or the 16 characters `\ ` `x` `a` `b` `\ ` `x` `c` `d` …. Your individual codes already can produce each.

Comment: Interesting ... seems to be a difference between python versions. Python2 behaves as I expect, but Python3 prints the characters...

root@debian# python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr 16 2021, 14:02:03) 
>>> int2chr(0xabcdffff, 4)
'\xab\xcd\xff\xff'
>>> 

root@debian# python3
Python 3.6.10 (default, Feb 12 2021, 15:16:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
>>> int2chr(0xabcdffff, 4)
'����'
>>>

Comment: Python 2's `str` type is effectively Python 3's `bytes` for this kind of task.